# Is there a non-REST version control API to Visual Studio Team Services?

Tags: version-control, azure-devops

I'm looking at whether we can migrate our old on-premises TFS 2010 server to Visual Studio Team Services. We all have MSDN subscriptions so it looks promising. But we have an app we wrote to keep our SQL scripts in version control. The app uses the old Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client & Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client object model approach. I'm lost in the Marketing-focused pages about VS Team Services and all I can find is talk of a REST API. Would we really have to re-write this part of the app or am I just missing something?

(I know we could do the source control bit from Visual Studio but the app has other functionality I haven't seen elsewhere.)

Can anyone advise me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TFS 2010 API works just fine with Team Services, so your app should just work.

You can currently use the 2010, 2012, 2013, and 2015 TFS client API's for TFS against Team Services. Team Services is just TFS on the internet...

Comment: Thanks, MrHinsh. I did try that first, just in case, but I got some errors so I figured I'd better RTFM. Then I got baffled by the docs. Better dig a bit deeper into the errors.